# Are Eth Wallets created on Magic Supported?

Tags: wallets

I was approached by a new NFT Generator Company to collaborate and do an NFT release as a collection of 54 artists.

However, it went south and I am trying to find a different platform to host and distribute these digital artworks to honour my commitment to the buyers and artists. Tezos has come highly recommended and so I am looking to set up an account and upload these artworks so the artists and I can push and move them as per our original plan.

Here's my question and problem (sorry for the long winded way of getting there), most of the artists involved in this project have never sold an nft before or dealt in crypto, so we got each of them (aside from about 10 who have wallets) to create a wallet through magic. This was a long and painful process that came with a lot of hesitation for most. Now I know these are eth wallets and I'm wondering if they are compatible with Tezos as I'd like to set up contracts with each artist to individually sell and transfer funds directly to them, but don't think I'd be able to get each of them to create a new wallet to accept tezos instead of eth.

So in short, does Tezos support eth and if I use the wallet addresses I currently have for each artist (to access eth) will this be supported and pay them?

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**:

no Tezos doesn't support eth

**Longer answer**:

- You didn't share any links in your post, is this the "Magic" you are referring too? It claims to support Tezos. While it would mean still using Tezos, at least the same app could be used: https://magic.link/docs/dedicated/blockchains/tezos/taquito
- There are "wrapped" ETH tokens, and bridges setup so that you can move funds across both chains, similar to most EVM based chains/L2s etc. This is quite a technical process and likely confusing for anyone who was already hesitant to setup wallets. This would be the closest thing to "supporting eth". But it doesn't allow to transfer NFTs or interact with with eth based applications via Tezos.
- There is a new EVM compatible rollup being worked on that will allow eth applications to move to the Tezos ecosystem, but this is in Beta and a while away yet + would require other apps to move. Not something I think that you could rely on in the short term if there is a pressing need to move quickly.
- https://objkt.com is the main NFT marketplace on Tezos, it has attracted and become very popular in the NFT space with artists. I understand the issues you've mentioned and the hesitation, but likely the best approach is to try convince them to join an art focused community and explain the issues with eth. Tezos has drastically lower fees and all the same features. It would be a far smoother experience than trying to deal with bridges
- Wallets such as https://kukai.app on Tezos also allow the creation of wallets by just logging into your social account. While i'd always recommend to have a seed based wallet as a cold wallet and to use the social as a hot wallet. Using the social based login can greatly help reduce the initial friction